# Toggle class upon change of data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, woocommerce

I'm working on a shopping cart and my client wants it to have one background when it's empty and another one when it has items. So here's what I got as a mark up:

```
<a href="#" id="shopping-cart" data-count="0" class="trigger cart">
<span>
</span>
</a>
```

The changes on the data-count are being handled on server side and updated via php my problem is that I have no idea how to make jquery read the data-count and make the if statement so it reads

```
if data-count= 0 then add .empty  
else data-count > 0 then add .full
```

Also, I'm not sure if I should use `.addClass`  or `.toggleClass` from empty to full, I'm sorry, so far all my attempts to write jquery have failed and the  handler for all that is on vacation so I would appreciate all the help.

A decision was made to change the plugin being used and now I tried to replicate this on the new one and cant seem to wrap my head around it to achieve it the new code available looks something like this:

```
<?php global $woocommerce; ?>

<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" 
title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">
<?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you do this ?  :

```
$cart = sprintf(_n('%d', cart::$cart_contents_count, 'mini-cart'), cart::$cart_contents_count);

if($cart >= '1')
{
?> 
<a href="#" id="shopping-cart" data-count="$cart" class="trigger cart">
<span>
</span>
</a> <?php
}
else 
{ ?>
<a href="#" id="shopping-cart" data-count="0" class="trigger cart">
<span>
</span>
</a>
<?php
}
```

this way you do not need to use `jQuery` to hide elements that are not needed.

Comment: the thing is, I cant mess with the data-count it has the plugin's code to deliver how many items does the cart has I just put the 0 in there as an example, it has something like this:

    
  data-count="<?php echo sprintf(_n('%d', cart::$cart_contents_count, 'mini-cart'), cart::$cart_contents_count);?>"

Comment: Cant get my head around it, it was decided that we would switch to another commerce plugin and it stopped working and I figured it would work out the same way but didn't, I would appreciate any extra help

Comment: check your PHP version.. maybe it has something to do with.. other than that.. I cannot help you :( .. the code should work .. because it has not problem at all !

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.cart').data('count')
```

Gives the value of count.